# ExpressionEngine on Vagrant VM: "Thumbnail could not be created for the image" error

Tags: linux, permissions, virtual-machine, expressionengine, vagrant

We're running ExpressionEngine 2.6.1 on a Vagrant VM (CentOS 6.2), with the EE files in the Vagrant "shared folder". When I ssh into the Vagrant machine, I see the following permissions for the uploads folder and its children:

```
uploads:          drwxrxrwx   apache   apache
uploads/_thumbs:  drwxr-xr-x  apache   apache
```

We changed the ownership of those directories to the apache user and group just to see if that's what EE needed, but with no success. Previous to that we had:

```
uploads:          drwxrwxrwx  vagrant  apache
uploads/_thumbs:  drwxrwxrwx  vagrant  apache
```

and before that:

```
uploads:          drwxrwxrwx  vagrant  vagrant
uploads/_thumbs:  drwxrwxrwx  vagrant  vagrant
```

And in all three cases, when we try to upload an image to a content item, we get the following error:

> Thumbnail could not be created for the image. Please make sure the thumbnail directory is writable.

Does anybody have any ideas why this would be the case?

Answer (score 0):

What user and group do you need to be? The default user after you ssh is vagrant:vagrant.

```
chown -R user:group uploads
```

That will recursively chown all of the files and directories in uploads. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Yeah, you can only change that shared folder's group/owner by adding it to the Vagrantfile, ie `config.vm.share_folder "docroot", "/var/www/html/", "~/local/path", :group => "apache", :owner => "apache"`

Answer (score 0):

When we tried to reproduce the problem on a second computer running the exact same repo and exact same Vagrant set up, the problem disappeared. When we deleted the entire repo from the first computer and re-cloned, the problem went away as well.

Not a great answer, I know, but that's all I've got.